# Laravel Heroku App Suddenly Crashing after Deploy

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-blade

I made a few changes to a Blade template - no changes to controllers, etc. - and confirmed that there are no errors locally.

I pushed the changes to Github and triggered a build and deploy of my Laravel application.

However, my application didn't start and now the logs read:

```
2019-01-14T16:41:22.580202+00:00 app[web.1]: DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'public/'
2019-01-14T16:41:22.656846+00:00 app[web.1]: Optimizing defaults for 1X dyno...
2019-01-14T16:41:22.690437+00:00 app[web.1]: 2 processes at 256MB memory limit.
2019-01-14T16:41:22.707069+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm...
2019-01-14T16:41:23.935071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-14T16:41:23.815103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-01-14T16:41:23.815215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-01-14T16:41:23.914103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I tried to restart the dynos to see if that would have an effect but it didn't. I did some searching on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything that was particularly helpful.

I do have a user.ini file with the 256MB memory limit set (as is reflected in the logs) but didn't make any changes to that.

I have not tried reverting my changes to the Blade template because I don't understand how that could lead to this boot timeout error.

Comment: Revert and see if the reverted version works. That'll at least tell you whether the Blade changes are what's doing it. If that fixes it, post your Blade changes here.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, the reverted version works - I feel a bit dumb for not just trying that before posting here. I made two separate changes after that rollback, so I am going to roll forward one change at a time until I find the one that's causing the issue, and then I'll post the Blade changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @ceejayoz helped me figure out what was wrong. Reverting changes one by one led me to a fairly obvious issue that I was able to correct and redeploy without issue.